# Block certain Addresses from being Crawled Robots.txt

Tags: indexing, seo, robots.txt, search-engine-bots

I've been asked (in order to improve SEO results) to remove a certain web address from a Robots.txt.

I'm struggling (SEO is not my forte) to figure out how to block a certain domain, even though both addresses point to the same website.

**For Example:**

http://foo.example.com -- Web Address I need to stop from being Indexed 
http://www.examplefoo.com -- Web Address I want to be indexed

From What I can tell, using a disallow / will only block from both (as they are the same site)

Any help?! Sorry if this is a silly question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
If your first domain in up, you should redirect it to your second domain.

Sample (width htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxx.ir$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.ir$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yyy.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Step 2:
You should remove all urls (from first domain) by remove urls in webmaster tools (directory all)

good luck